# How to enumerate AD organizational units where inheritance is disabled

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I enumerate Active Directory organizational units where permissions inheritance has been disabled, programmatically using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could manually code it and query the **SE_DACL_PROTECTED** attribute using the **Invoke-FindOUpermissions.ps1** script as a baseline https://gist.github.com/neKuehn/61f70b2d54a4344b5638c0625e2f8ca6

or try the following

How to get an Active Directory OU permissions report - https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/149278-how-to-get-an-active-directory-ou-permissions-report

Active Directory Security, Permission and ACL Analysis http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/liza.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler method -- it should provide a list of the OUs that have security inheritance disabled:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * | where {($_.nTSecurityDescriptor.AreAccessRulesProtected -eq $true)}
```